# Header Custom View: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, null, tableview

I'm getting an error when I run my code. The error is all in the line below within the viewForHeaderInSection function.

```
let header:friendsListSectionHeader = self.friendsTableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("friendsSection") as! friendsListSectionHeader
```

and I reference it like this in the viewDidLoad.

```
let nib2 = UINib(nibName: "friendsListSectionHeader", bundle: nil)
        friendsTableView.registerNib(nib2, forCellReuseIdentifier: "friendsSection")
```

I do have a custom view for a cell above this if that does anything. Everything builds, but I get an error that I'm unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Option value.

My .xib and UITableViewHeaderFooterView class are all referenced correctly.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just using the wrong registration method, you're registering a cell where you should be using `registerNib:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:`